# Is it possible to use a continuous legend with discrete values with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a bathymetry map with `tidyterra` and `ggplot2`.

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.23
library(tidyterra)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidyterra'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(ggplot2)

f <- system.file("extdata/volcano2.tif", package = "tidyterra")
r <- rast(f)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_contour_filled(data = r, breaks = seq(80, 200, 5)) +
  scale_fill_hypso_d(palette = "colombia_bathy")
```

[image]

I am using many different contours (levels) so the legend includes many keys. It is possible to change it into a continuous legend? I have tried to use `guide_colorsteps()` which is a bit better, but still a lot of levels in it. I would like, for example, have a continuous legend with breaks at every 50 meters while keeping the countours at 5 meters.

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_contour_filled(data = r, breaks = seq(80, 200, 5)) +
  scale_fill_hypso_d(
    palette = "colombia_bathy",
    guide = guide_colorsteps()
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: consider simply setting some of the labels to `""` using the function form of the label argument (`labels = function(breaks) ifelse(breaks %in% seq(80, 200, 50), breaks, "")`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `guide_colorbar` requires a continuous scale. But if some faking is fine for you you could create your continuous colorbar via second plot, extract it via e.g. `cowplot::get_legend` and glue it to your main plot. Not perfect and requires some fiddling with the plot size and the heights.

```
library(terra)
library(tidyterra)
library(ggplot2)

f <- system.file("extdata/volcano2.tif", package = "tidyterra")
r <- rast(f)

p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_contour_filled(data = r, breaks = seq(80, 200, 5)) +
  scale_fill_hypso_d(
    palette = "colombia_bathy"
  )

legend <- (ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = r) +
  scale_fill_hypso_c(
    palette = "colombia_bathy",
    guide = guide_colorbar(axis.limits = TRUE)
  )) |> cowplot::get_legend()

library(patchwork)

(p1 + guides(fill = "none")) + legend +
  plot_layout(widths = c(4, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to avoid faking it, but might be forced to do it :), THank you!